# JDK source: code repetition Collection.java and Set.java

Tags: java

In JDK 8, `java.util.Collection` starts with

```
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E> {
    // Query Operations

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this collection.  If this collection
     * contains more than <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt> elements, returns
     * <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt>.
     *
     * @return the number of elements in this collection
     */
    int size();
```

Interestingly, `java.util.Set` starts with

```
public interface Set<E> extends Collection<E> {
    // Query Operations

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this set (its cardinality).  If this
     * set contains more than <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt> elements, returns
     * <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt>.
     *
     * @return the number of elements in this set (its cardinality)
     */
    int size();
```

What is the purpose of overriding method declarations in interfaces? Why does not `extends` suffice?

**EDIT** `java.util.List` also shows redundancy, and the javadoc of `List.size()` is only minimally different that of `Collection.size()`, and does not introduce any new term:

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
// Query Operations

/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this list.  If this list contains
 * more than <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt> elements, returns
 * <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt>.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this list
 */
int size();
```

Answer (score 6):

Overriding a method can be used for a lot of reasons besides to change the behavior.  It can change the signature of the method (refining the return type with a covariant override), add annotations, broaden the accessibility (turning a protected method into public in a subclass), or refine the specification (expressed as Javadoc).  In this case, the override exists so that the `Set` Javadoc could define the term "cardinality".

Comment: Seems a bit of a shallow reason to override a method.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Thanks, but what about `List`? It does not introduce a new term in its javadoc ...